# Adding multiple WHERE .. AND statements to the same SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that combines a variable number of AND WHERE statements.

One statement would look like

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE field_id=16
AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

but I need to return one array of results from a variable amount of fields so field_id's of 16,18,20,25 with each field_id having a specific "AND value..." criteria.

How could I go about doing this to return on set of values?

I am also getting the criteria for the search from a html form and processing it using php (wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `field_id` needs to relate to the `value` field criteria, you need to `AND` your `field_id` and `value` values together while `OR`ing each set of criteria.

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE (field_id=16 AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 100)
OR (field_id=17 AND value between 101 and 199)
OR (field_id=18 AND value between 201 and 299)
OR (...
```

You may also be looking for an `IN` statement.  Which would look like this.

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE (field_id IN (16,17,18) AND value IN (100,200,300))
...
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8ea0/2)

Comment: Could OR be replaced by AND? Because the criteria has to be all one critiera, not between  1 and 2 or between 2 and 3 but between 1 and 2 AND 2 and 3

Comment: @user2981393 Not quite sure I follow.  Take the value 50.  If your criteria are between 1 and 100 AND between 101 and 199, then 50 would not be caught because it doesnt fall between 101 and 199..

Comment: If you changed `OR` to `AND` in this query, there would never be any records shown.  Because a field_id cannot be 16 AND 17 at the same time.  Make sense?

Comment: @user2981393, perhaps there is part of your specification that is missing?  Are you trying to get a different set of data?

Comment: How about changing the query to show one set of results from a multiple amount of field_id's? like showing WHERE field_id=16 and VALUE=15...and in the same query, field_id=17 AND value=19 and returning one set of results? is that possible?

Comment: @user2981393, check my edits.  I think you are describing an `IN`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that looks better, for field_id IN (16,17,18) AND VALUE IN (100,200,300) would each parameter be matched up with each other? like 16=100,17=200 etc...?

Comment: No, they are not matched up.  If you want them matched up, then my first example does that.  `IN` simply gives you ALL 16's 17's and 18's that also have values of either 100,200 or 300.

Comment: I think your problem may lie in misunderstanding boolean logic.  Have you run that first query?

Comment: I have not run that query. The first example has a WHERE and then OR's. But I need the query to be strict as in all the criteria must be met for the returned results. Like field_id 16=100 AND 17=100 must be both met.

Comment: Check out the fiddle i just posted.  It will show you that it does exactly that.  A single record CANNOT equal both 16 AND 17.  Another way to look at it is you want (field id = 16 OR 17) AND (value = 100.)

Comment: @user2981393, adjust the data of the fiddle if you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61218/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-user2981393).

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of AND and OR conditions:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
WHERE (field_id=16 AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 100) 
  OR (field_id=18 AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 150)
  OR (field_id=20 AND value BETWEEN 10 AND 50)
  OR (field_id=25 AND value BETWEEN 100 AND 500)
....
```